# Finding parameter for ODE to get polynomial solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE

$$
(x^2+2x)y'' + \theta y=0
$$

has a quadratic polynomial solution. I want to find $\theta$ for which the solution is a quadratic polynomial.

I assumed solution in the form of $y=ax^2+bx+c$

So, $y'=2ax+b$

$y''=2a$

Putting these values in the ODE,
$$
x^2(2a+a\theta )+x(4a+b\theta)+c\theta = 0\\ 
so, 2a+a\theta=0 \implies \theta=-2\\
4a+b\theta=0 \implies \theta=-4a/b \\
c\theta=0 \implies c=0 , \theta=0
$$

I am confused with these equations. Which of the above equations can give me solution in form of quadratic polynomial? It seems that I get different answer from each equation. Can someone comment?

Furthermore, these equations will give me some relations between $a,b$ and $c=0$. However I am confused whether these relations will be useful or not - I need value of $\theta$ and not the quadratic polynomial itself. If I substitute $\theta =-2$ in the ODE, I do not get quadratic polynomial solution. I checked the algebra and believe that I didn't messed up anywhere. Still, far from what is needed.

Comment: Any suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 1):

Note: I haven't verified the algebra.

You have $\theta = -2$. This is absolute. It's the only value of $\theta$ that works.
The remaining equations tell you some constraints on $a$, $b$ and $c$. In particular, $c=0$ and $a = \frac12b$

Comment: added some comments in the main question. As you said, I get relations among variables $a,b$ and $c-0$, but I am interested in value of parameter for which the result should be quadratic polynomial. I guess, even if I get relationships among variables, they are not heading me to anywhere.

Comment: WA gives $y(x) = c_1 x (x+2)+c_2 (x (-(x+2) \log(x)+(x+2) \log(x+2)-2)-2)$ which is a quadratic as given for $c_2 = 0$.